# Yii relations result non-existing items (cache issue?)

Tags: caching, yii, yii-relations

I have set relations: `'teamDrivers' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'TeamDriver', 'team_id')` in my Team model

So if I want I can: `print_r($this->teamDrivers);` in my Team. Just for demonstration.

Now the problem is that this kind of code produces a list of items that have already been removed form database! Via `CActiveDataProvider` with `CDbCriteria` those items are not reached.

If I log out from my app and then log back in everything seems to be working.

So is there some cache that takes care of those relations or what is this mystery? And how do I clear that cache?

Comment: Are you executing the `print_r($this->teamDrivers)` immediately after deleting the `teamDrivers`?

Comment: I can wait few minutes and it still produces the same effect.

Comment: Hmm, this is less likely to help due to the fact that a few minutes can pass with no change (I assume that also means a new page load),but have you tried `$this->refresh()` before you attempt the `print_r`? That should wipe out the short term cache in the model, although reloading a page would do the same.

Comment: Actually that was the problem. There was old model still used.

Comment: @Gessle even when models are deleted through `CActiveRecord::delete()` the model instance still holds all the data it had before. This can be useful for undoing the delete action or doing some clean up after deletes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case UserIdentity object had old information and team was got through it. Refreshing was the solutions.